# Keyboard manipulation

Tags: c#, c++, c, winapi, keyboard

I'm going to be very specific.
This is what i want to do in windows:

1. Write code that makes the keyboard to send me characters, i am interested in the time it takes the keyboard to send a character signal.
2. Find a way of ensuring that this code gets the priority it is undesirable to have it queued or interrupted by the OS
3. Find a way of reading keyboard status signals

i have been reading a lot, all i am getting is how to simulate a keyboard..i just need to be pointed in the right direction

Comment: Look for Shadow Keylogger and decompile it if it's not open source. Its written in C#

Comment: 'i am interested in the time it takes the keyboard to send a character signal' - between where and where?  You going to have special hardware to detect the key down action on a real physical keyboard?  Also, the OS does not generate interrupts, peripheral hardware does, causing a driver to run - something you are going to have to write to receive keypress input without software queueing.

Answer (score 1):

The most common option is using Windows [hook](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644959%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)  - or WH_Keyboard or WH_JOURNALRECORD. The difference is that WH_JOURNALRECORD does not require a separate DLL.

Or you can write your own keyboard driver. It may be implemented in 2 ways:  your own full keyboard driver instead of the standard driver or an additional [filter driver](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff545890%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) .

And finally you can write a rootkit.
It can be implemented in user mode by intercepting [csrss.exe](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Client/Server_Runtime_Subsystem) process.

As I am not sure what your purpose is, I am not going into more details.

Comment: I found out that avoiding queuing can be done with a technique called direct manipulation. I haven't been very lucky with part 1 of my question above, i am only getting keyboardInput using win32 api. Sorry for not being clear the first time, i want to write code that sends a signal to the keyboard and makes it to send back a character that will be specified(an echo of sorts), i need to use the time the echo takes in an application i am writing